# Numeros aleatorios a partir de dato en excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, flask, aplicación-web

Cordial saludo para todos, tengo un codigo base realizado en python-flask, en el cual se carga un archivo excel y se toma informacion de dos columnas nombres y nroBoletas, nombre se usara como clave y nroBoletas se usuará el numero almacenado para generar una lista de numeros aleatorios tomando el dato de la columna para crear la lista con una longitud al dato tomado, por ejemplo, Nombre: Alberto, nroBoletas: 700, por lo cual la clave sera Alberto, y como valor sera una lista con 700 elementos/numeros generados.

```
# Tamaño del lote a recorrer
tamaño_lote = 500

# Diccionario para mantener un registro de las boletas asignadas a cada persona
boletas_asignadas_por_persona = {}

# Utiliza un diccionario para almacenar temporalmente los datos entre solicitudes
data_dict = {}
```

a continuacion comparto la ruta en flask la cual realiza todo el proceso de crear y asignar numeros aleatorios unicos

```
@app.route("/subirArchivo", methods=["POST"])
def subirArchivo():
global data_dict

#semilla para generar siempre los mismo numeros de boletas
random.seed(123)

#guarda en la variable el archivo que se subio por medio del formulario html
archivo = request.files['archivosq']
    
#guarda el nombre del archivo que se subio sin la extension
nombre_archivo_original = os.path.splitext(archivo.filename)[0]
    
# Lee el archivo y asigna el DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(archivo, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Restablecer el diccionario al cargar un nuevo archivo
data_dict = {}

# Reiniciar el conjunto de boletas asignadas
boletas_asignadas = set()

#Función para asignar los nros de las boletas a cada persona, los parametros "nombre" y "cantidad_boletas" son los datos de los nombres y la cantidad de boletas a las que tiene derecho cada persona, dichos datos son sacados del archivo excel
def asignar_boletas(nombre, cantidad_boletas):
    #se crea conjunto el cual guardara los numeros de las boletas asignadas a la persona, se usa un conjunto ya que no permite valores repetidos
    boletas_asignadas_a_la_persona = set()
    #mientras el numero de elementos del conjunto "boletas_asignadas_a_la_persona" es menor a "cantidad_boletas" el cual es el numero de boletas a las que tiene derecho cada persona, dato sacado del archivo excel, por lo cual mientras sea mejor generará numeros aleatorios y los agregará al conjunto
    while len(boletas_asignadas_a_la_persona) < cantidad_boletas:
        #variable que guarda los numeros generados, que van desde 1 hasta el numero total de boletas por todas las personas que participaran
        numero_boleta = random.randint(1, 150000)
        #si el numero generado no está en el conjunto general "boletas_asignadas" y el conjunto "boletas_asignadas_a_la_persona" los agrega respectivamente
        if numero_boleta not in boletas_asignadas and numero_boleta not in boletas_asignadas_a_la_persona:
            boletas_asignadas_a_la_persona.add(numero_boleta)
            boletas_asignadas.add(numero_boleta)
            
    #crea diccionario teniendo como clave los nombres de la persona y como valor una lista con los nros de las boletas generados
    boletas_asignadas_por_persona[nombre] = list(boletas_asignadas_a_la_persona)

# Iterar por lotes
inicio = 0
fin = tamaño_lote
#se itera por lotes
while inicio < len(df):
    data_dict = dict(zip(df['Nombres'][inicio:fin], df['NroBoletas'][inicio:fin]))
    #Iterar a través del diccionario de datos traidos del archivo excel del lote actual, llamando a la funcion pasando como parametro el nombre y la cantidad de boletas a asignar
    for nombre, cantidad in data_dict.items():
        asignar_boletas(nombre, cantidad)

    
    inicio = fin
    fin += tamaño_lote

#agrega a la columna "BoletasAsignadas" tomando en cuenta el nombre de la persona, gracias a la funcion "map" la cual toma los valores de la columna "Nombres" y busca los valores que corresponden en el diccionario creado
df['BoletasAsignadas'] = df['Nombres'].map(boletas_asignadas_por_persona)
    
# Guarda el DataFrame modificado en un nuevo archivo Excel concatenando el nombre del archivo subido con "Resultado"
df.to_excel(f'{nombre_archivo_original} Resultado.xlsx', index=False)

#Agrega al diccionario como clave el nombre del archivo original que se sube a la pagina y como valor toma los registros y/o datos correspondientes del archivo lo que permite organizar y facilitar el acceso a la informacion de cada archivo subido en la pagina
data_dict[nombre_archivo_original] = df.to_dict(orient='records')

return redirect(url_for('importacion_excel'))
```

lo que he observado en el archivo excel resultado generado en el cual se agrega la nueva columna la cual tiene para cada registro una lista con numeros aleatorios generados, me di cuenta que si una persona tiene por ejemplo que generarle 2000 numeros, en el excel de resultado solamente tiene 1450 numeros, validé imprimiendo una clave la cual tiene una lista de mas de 2000 elementos con "len" y efectivamente me imprime el numero de elementos que debe ser, por lo cual en el archivo excel que flask me genera es donde tengo el error, ya que son varios registros los cuales tiene mas de 1500 numeros que se deben generar. No se si me expliqué bien, quedo atento.